# R: don't write log file for VennDiagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I use `R` (version 3.1.2) and the package `VennDiagram` (version 1.6.16).

Since my last update the `VennDiagram` package creates a log file called `VennDiagramDATE_TIME.log` (with `DATE` and `TIME` being date and time at creation) in the current working directory.

How can suppress this log file? Or delete it as soon as the diagram is done? I haven't found anything about this in the manual...

Comment: You could always use `file.remove()`.

Comment: yes, but then I have to find out the name of the log file first. Which I could do but I was hoping there is something easier to suppress the writing of the logfile in the first place.

Comment: The source code is not huge - - just go in there and comment out the lines which write the file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like Ed Hagen already mentioned, **VennDiagram** is making usage of the *futile.logger* package. 
You can suppress logging messages below *ERROR* severity, by setting the threshold to the corresponding logger. In your case:

```
futile.logger::flog.threshold(futile.logger::ERROR, name = "VennDiagramLogger")
venn.diagram(...)
```

should do the trick.

For more infomation about the usage of futile.logger see http://www.r-bloggers.com/better-logging-in-r-aka-futile-logger-1-3-0-released/.

Comment: The default really should be no log file

Comment: I agree with stevec. Doing this as default for what is essentially a *plotting library* is truly dreadful. The package author needs to _flog_ (!) this particular hobby horse more appropriately and preferably elsewhere. Meanwhile there's the venn package, as one alternative.

Answer (score 4):

VennDiagram uses the futile.logger package. To suppress logging, try:

```
flog.threshold(ERROR)
```